# Inverse function of function with 2 variables.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inverse, inverse-function, inverse-problems

Maybe this question has possible duplicate or something, but i still don't get it.

Suppose i have this function :

$$f(x,y)=x+y$$

What is the inverse of this? Is it possible?
Bcz, i'm not learning the inverse of multivariable function on calculus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that your function is $$f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$$
Since $f(1,-1)=f(2,-2)=0$ your function is not injective and therefore it does not have an inverse.